# How to parse complex json in GWT?

Tags: json, gwt

I know how to parse simple json, but dont know how to parse a more complex json (array contains another array).

example json string:
[{"linkID":"101030","connectingPoints":[[37.7888, -122.388], [37.803918106204456, -122.36559391021729], [37.8107, -122.364]]},{"linkID":"101040","connectingPoints":null}]

My jsni:

```
public class LinkDefinition extends JavaScriptObject
{
    protected LinkDefinition()
    {
    }

    public final native String getLinkID()
    /*-{
        return this.linkID;
    }-*/;

    public final native JsArray<LatLon> getConnectingPoints()
    /*-{
        return this.connectingPoints;
    }-*/;
}
```

and

```
public class LatLon extends JavaScriptObject
{
    public final int LAT = 0;
    public final int LON = 1;

    protected LatLon()
    {   
    }

    public final native double getLat()
    /*-{
        return this[LAT}; // edited
    }-*/;

    public final native double getLon()
    /*-{
        return this[LON]; // edited
    }-*/;
}
```

Now I got the error message

> [ERROR] [MyProj] - Line x: Instance fields cannot be used in
>   subclasses of JavaScriptObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the `public final int` fields in `LatLon`. Change them to `static` to turn them into constants and fix the error.

You also have an issue in your code in that `getLat` and `getLon` return `this` instead of `this[0]` and `this[1]` (or `this[@packageOf.LatLon::LAT]` and `this[@packageOf.LatLon::LON]`)

Comment: opps, my mistake, because I was doing different code combination to see if I can get away from the error message. I edit my post now.

Comment: Still, `this[LAT]` is wrong (would reference a `LAT` JS variable, not a Java/GWT constant or field).

Comment: the compiler is not happy with @packageOf.LatLon::LAT, so I use hard-coded 0 and 1 instead of constant, and it works.

Comment: Just to be sure: you indeed replaced `packagedOf.` with the full package of the `LatLon` class? (hint: Eclipse with the Google Plugin should provide autocomplete)

Answer (score 2):

You can read this doc about JavaScriptObject restrictions...
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/doc/helpInfo/jsoRestrictions.html

Otherwise, everything that Thomas said. The main error is public final int fiels (change them to static exactly as he suggested)

Comment: the document doesn't explicitly telling we cant use public final for member variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse JSON string and access fields instead of using overlays. You can do it with [`com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html). It has two methods

1. `parseLenient()`, which you should only use if you are sure there won't be any JS code injected (eg. comes from your server)
2. `parseStrict()` which is slower, but is resistant to code injection